# If columns of a square matrix are linearly independent then the matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It's known that the the columns of an invertible matrix are linearly independent ,but does the converse does hold?

I was reading the solution provided [here](https://yutsumura.com/three-linearly-independent-vectors-in-r3-form-a-basis-three-vectors-spanning-r3-form-a-basis/),but unfortunately could not find a proof of that.

I like to see a proof of that (if the claim it's true) and see a Counterexample if it does not hold in general.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what tools you're allowed. Personally, I would look at the contrapositive. If the columns are not linearly independent, then the matrix has a determinant of zero, and therefore is not invertible.

Comment: @  Eevee Trainer,It looks that the claim "Columns of a square matrix are linearly independent if and only if the matrix is invertible" does hold,at least that's what I see in the link ,but as I said I could not find any proof of the converse .